# RestTemplate with Proxy with kerberos authentication in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, proxy, kerberos

I'm trying to access rest api through my companies proxy server this requires me authenticate with the proxy.

I can access the outside world using curl with the parameters:

`curl -v -s -user $kerbrosId -x $ProxyServer:$proxyPort --proxy-negotiate https://google.com`
I receive the following output:

```
Enter proxy password for user '$user':
*   Trying $proxyIP:$proxyPort...
* Connected to $proxyURL ($proxyIP) port $proxyPort (#0)
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to google.com:443
* Proxy auth using Negotiate with user 'bradsw'
> CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate ${shortBase64token}
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE ${longerBase64token}
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 5621
<
* Ignore 5621 bytes of response-body
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to google.com:443
* Proxy auth using Negotiate with user '$user'
> CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate ${evenLongerBase64token}
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://www.google.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2022 22:09:00 GMT
< Expires: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 22:09:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 220
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
```

I have tried a million variations of

```
RestTemplate(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
    HttpClientBuilder.create()
      .setProxy(HttpHost(proxyUrl, proxyPort))
      //other calls here to set things up
      .build()
    )
)
```

Nothing seems to authenticate correctly. I get back a 407 PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED with the companies default call the help desk if your browser doesn't work page in my stack trace.

Our systems are configured with an appropriate kbr5.config file so that should not be the issue & in other places in the code we are getting an SSO token a based on a ticket stored by kinit using the equivalent of `RestTemplate().getForEntity("${sso-endpoint}", String::class.java)`.

I would ideally like to be able to delegate credentials to the OS via logged on user (either windows or REL based Linux systems) though I would consider simply authenticating at all a win at this point. I'm working in Kotlin but can easily translate a Java solution to Kotlin.

Any ideas appreciated?